# Valgrind Error: failed in UME with error 22

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

I am playing around with tool development in Valgrind and am getting the following error:

```
valgrind: mmap(0x8048000, 4096) failed in UME with error 22 (Invalid argument).
valgrind: this can be caused by executables with very large text, data or bss segments.
```

but my executable has nothing but simple variable assignments. I am not able to understand how to fix this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this for my case and submitted a patch:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=290061

If you or anyone else having this problem are building your executable with `-pie`, this might help you too.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have an answer, but there is an open bug on this issue.

http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138424

Comment: +1 ouch - afaict, this bug still lives in Ubuntu 12.10 (amd64), valgrind 3.7.0 when I did an mmap read on a 4.3GB file.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error as well. In my situation, the program I was analyzing contained huge statically-allocated arrays, which caused the `.bss` segment size to blow up (over 2 GiB):

```
$ size ./MyExe
   text    data     bss          dec          hex      filename
  50324    2480     2338486216   2338539020   8b63460c MyExe.exe
```

The large arrays were only necessary for testing under heavy loads, so I defined the arrays to be much smaller in the code and recompiled. This shrunk the `.bss` segment down to something more reasonable, and allowed me to run the program normally with Valgrind.

Note: It seemed I needed to get the `.bss` segment under `932000000` in order for Valgrind to run without the error, although this threshold seemed somewhat arbitrary.